# Варианты оценки производительности алгоритмов

Tags: c++, производительность, асимптотика

Какие есть варианты оценки производительности алгоритмов на С++???
P.S. Если можно, с простыми примерами.

Comment: в целом, с++ не имеет отношения к оценке производительности алгоритмов. Почитайте первый том Кнута - там все хорошо описано.

Comment: Из банальщины - считать количество сравнений и пересылок. Подсчет трудоемкости. Либо время выполнения засекать.

Comment: Почитайте Макконнелл Дж. Анализ алгоритмов.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/188010/

Answer (score 3):

На практике понадобится несколько оценок:

- O(1) - константное время,
- O(log(n)) - логарифмическое по основанию 2,
- O(n) - линейное,
- O(n log(n)) - линейно-логарифмическое,
- O(n^2) - квадратичное,
- а остальные более сложные стоит избегать, если только перемножение матриц не оптимизированным способом O(n^3).

Например O(1) константное время это доступ к массиву по индексу или к хэш-таблице в лучшем случае конечно, так же константное время доступа к мин/макс элемента в бинарной или Фибоначчиевой куче. Например линейный поиск элемента в массиве имеет сложность O(n) то есть само название поиска говорит о линейной сложности, а вот бинарный поиск в упорядоченном массиве имеет сложность O(log(n)) логарифмическую. Тоже самое и с алгоритмами сортировок, быстрая сортировка в лучшем случае даст линейно-логарифмическую сложность O(n log(n)), в худшем может дать квадратичную O(n^2) сложность как обычные сортировки пузырьком/выбором/вставкой. К примеру бинарное двоичное дерево поиска(BST) в не вырожденном дереве все операции имеют сложность O(log(n)) но если дерево станет вырожденным то сложность может станет линейной как в обычном связном списке O(n). Ещё нужно знать в каких алгоритмах используешь дополнительную память, каковы скрытые константы...

Answer (score 3):

производительность алгоритмов изучается в науке\предмете "Теория сложности алгоритмов" базисом для сравнения алгоритмов является "big-O notation"  (нотация "большое О") помимо этого есть ещё классы сложности (но это совсем другой уровень)

в общем через "big-O notation" измеряется время и объём памяти которое нужно алгоритму, при этом сравнение происходит независимо от языка, железа, нюансов реализации.

по своей сути это "линейка" для алгоритмов, и у этой линейки есть 3-и типа измерения: **примерно точное**(тета), **худший случай из лучших**(омега) и самое полезное **лучший случай из худших**(О).

ну и наконец-то ссылки на хабр

**Введение в анализ сложности алгоритмов:**

[(часть 1)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196560/)

[(часть 2)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195482/)

[(часть 3)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195996/)

[(часть 4)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196226/)

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь - теория, по количеству ресурсоемких итераций в зависимости от количества обрабатываемых данных (можно гуглить "сложность алгоритмов", "О-нотация").
Ну и практические тесты с замером времени.